# Rindler coordinate chart (family of parametric curves) in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pstricks, plot

Is it possible to make a plot like this with TikZ or other drawing packages?

[image: Coordinate transformation from (T,X) to (t,x)]

This plot visualizes a two parameter family of curves, given by

```
T = x Sinh(t)
X = x Cosh(t)
```

The pink curves are curves of constant t and curves of constant x.
The plot is from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_space

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, that kind of plot is totally within TikZ's remit. See below.

Remark: the curves of constant t on the picture you posted seem to be incorrectly labelled, e.g. "t=1" instead of "t=0.5", "t=2 instead of "t=1", etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{gridcolor}{RGB}{255 216 234} 
\definecolor{gridlabelcolor}{RGB}{255 24 131} 

\def\rnd#1{
    \pgfmathprintnumberto[precision=2]{#1}{\temp}\temp
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    scale=3,%
    maingrid/.style={draw=gridcolor,very thick},%
    subgrid/.style={draw=gridcolor,thin},%
    tlabels/.style={pos=0.88,above,sloped,yshift=-.3ex,gridlabelcolor},%
    label/.style={%
        postaction={%
            decorate,%
            transform shape,%
            decoration={%
                markings,%
                mark=at position .65 with \node #1;%
            }%
        }%
    },%
]%
    \pgfmathdeclarefunction{arcosh}{1}{\pgfmathparse{ln(#1+sqrt(#1+1)*sqrt(#1-1))}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Xmax}{1.2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\Tmax}{1.2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\g}{1}
    \newcommand\mylabelstyle\tiny

    % curves t=constant
    \foreach \t in {-3,-2.9375,...,3}{%
        \path[subgrid] (0,0) -- (\Xmax,{\Xmax*tanh(\g*\t)});
    }
    \foreach \t in {-3,-2.75,...,3}{%
        \path[maingrid] (0,0) -- (\Xmax,{\Xmax*tanh(\g*\t)});
    }   

    % curves x=constant
    \foreach \xx in {0.05,0.1,...,\Xmax}{%
        \path[subgrid]
            plot[domain=-{arcosh(\Xmax/\xx)/\g}:{arcosh(\Xmax/\xx)/\g}]
            ({\xx*cosh(\g*\x)},{\xx*sinh(\g*\x)});  
    }
    \foreach \xx in {0.2,0.4,...,1}{%
        \path[maingrid]
            plot[domain=-{arcosh(\Xmax/\xx)/\g}:{arcosh(\Xmax/\xx)/\g}]
            ({\xx*cosh(\g*\x)},{\xx*sinh(\g*\x)});  
    }

    % curve labels
    \foreach \t in {-1,-.5,...,1}{%
        \path (0,0) -- (\Xmax,{\Xmax*tanh(\g*\t)})
            node[tlabels] {\mylabelstyle$t=\t$};
    }
    \foreach \xx in {0.4,0.6,...,1.01}{%
        \path[gridlabelcolor,label={[above]{\mylabelstyle $x=\rnd{\xx}$}}]
            plot[domain=-{arcosh(\Xmax/\xx)/\g}:{arcosh(\Xmax/\xx)/\g}]
            ({\xx*cosh(\g*\x)},{\xx*sinh(\g*\x)});  
    }

    % X-axis, T-axis, and dashed lines t=+/-infty 
    \draw[thick,-stealth] (0,0) -- (\Xmax,0) node[below] {$X$};
    \draw[thick,-stealth] (0,0) -- (0,\Tmax) node[left] {$T$};
    \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (\Xmax,\Tmax) 
        node[pos=0.37,above,sloped,yshift=-.3ex] {\mylabelstyle$x=0$}
        node[tlabels,black] {\mylabelstyle$t=\infty$};
    \draw[dashed] (0,0) -- (\Xmax,-\Tmax)
        node[tlabels,black] {\mylabelstyle$t=-\infty$};     
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is such a faithful reproduction I could only tell that the picture wasn't the original by looking at the font of the labels!

Answer (score 9):

With PSTricks but not completed...

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=15pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-math}
\def\T(#1,#2){#1*SINH(#2)}
\def\X(#1,#2){#1*COSH(#2)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-4)(4,4)
    \rput[bl](-1,-3.5){%
        \begin{pspicture*}(-1,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)
            \psset{linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,linecolor=gray,plotpoints=500,algebraic}
            \multido{\n=-2.0+0.2}{21}{\psparametricplot{0}{4}{\X(t,\n)|\T(t,\n)}}
            \multido{\n=0.0+0.2}{21}{\psparametricplot{-2}{2}{\X(\n,t)|\T(\n,t)}}
        \end{pspicture*}}   
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-1,-4)(4,4)[$X$,0][$T$,90]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

### *Animation*

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-math}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=5pt

\def\T(#1,#2){#1*SINH(#2)}
\def\X(#1,#2){#1*COSH(#2)}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-4)(4,4)\pause
    \rput[bl](-1,-3.5){%
        \begin{pspicture*}(-1,-3.5)(3.5,3.5)
            \psset{linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth,linecolor=gray,plotpoints=500,algebraic}
            \multido{\n=-2.0+0.2}{21}{\psparametricplot{0}{4}{\X(t,\n)|\T(t,\n)}\pause}
            \multido{\n=0.0+0.2}{21}{\psparametricplot{-2}{2}{\X(\n,t)|\T(\n,t)}\pause}
        \end{pspicture*}}   
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-1,-4)(4,4)[$X$,0][$T$,90]
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've really got to get into PSTricks! Can you recommend a good (yet pedestrian) tutorial?

Comment: @Jubobs: I am preparing the free pedestrian tutorial. By the way, there are a few free PSTricks tutorials on the web, ones which are good for beginner were written by TUG India. Visit  [this link](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=doc/docs) and locate TUG India on the right side of the two-column list.